# C# missing method in Npgsql Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I have an error when I try to run the following line:

```
FlowsQuerieStartDate tmp = context.FlowsQuerieStartDates

.FirstOrDefault(x =\>       x.Client.Equals(connectionToSQLDatabase.ClientName));

    FlowsQuerieStartDate tmp = 
       context.FlowsQuerieStartDates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Client.Equals(connectionToSQLDatabase.ClientName));
```

The Exception text is :

> 'Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Npgsql.TypeMapping.NpgsqlTypeMapping> Npgsql.TypeMapping.INpgsqlTypeMapper.get_Mappings()'.'

This is the mapping class:

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System;
    
    namespace PostgreSQL.FlowQueryStartDate
    {
    
        public class FlowsQuerieStartDateContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<FlowsQuerieStartDate> FlowsQuerieStartDates { get; set; }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("constring");
            }
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<FlowsQuerieStartDate>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.ToTable("FlowsQuerieStartDate", "public");
    
                    entity.Property(e => e.Client).HasColumnName("Client");
    
                    entity.Property(e => e.StartDate).HasColumnName("StartDate");
    
                    entity.HasNoKey();
                });
            }
        }
    
        public class FlowsQuerieStartDate
        {
            public string Client { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

.NET framework 4.7.2

Microsoft.EntityFramework version 3.1.3

Npgsql version 6.0.3

Npsql.EntityFramework.PostgreSQL version 3.1.0

Any suggestion? It's blowing my mind...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

1. Lower (through the NuGet Package Manager) the "Npgsql version 6.0.3" to "Npgsql version 4.1.9",
   it should be noted that at that point (at least if you're are working with WinForms) you should delete the  Npgsql version 6.0.3 dependency reference in the "App.config" file.
2. Also my "Npsql.EntityFramework.PostgreSQL version" is set to  3.1.18", althought I believe your current one should suffice.

If this does not work for you, a disscussion on that topic can be found on the following link: https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/issues/2544